# How do you get a HTTP url for an item in amazon s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I am trying to upload a file onto the s3 bucket for amazon. However, I need a HTTP url. Do you guys know any way for me to do this? I am using nodejs right now and I can only get signed URLs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should be in the S3 docs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest` class for this purpose.

```
public static String writeToS3(File file, String folder) {
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3 s3Client = new com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client(
            getAWSCredentials());
    String key = file.getName();
    System.out.println("Going to write to key " + folder + key + " in S3");
    s3Client.putObject(BUCKET, folder + key, file);

    // This generates a URL that can be used to download the uploaded file.
    Date expiration = new Date();
    long msec = expiration.getTime();
    msec += S3_URL_VALIDITY_PERIOD_MILLISEC;
    expiration.setTime(msec);
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(
            BUCKET, folder + key);
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);
    URL s = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
    if (s == null) {
        System.out.println("Url returned was null");
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println("S3 Url: " + s.toString());
    return s.toString();
}
```

Complete Java code can be found here: http://design-interviews.blogspot.in/2015/07/java-code-to-read-and-write-objects-in-AWS-S3.html

Comment: This is for Java not Javascript/Nodejs unfortunatly